# C# (Mono): Restarting process on program failure

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm fairly new with working in Mono and would like to know how I can force my console application to restart upon exception under a linux environment. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the process dies, you can use something like [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to keep it running. Brief description:

> Monit can start a process if it does not run, restart a process if it does not respond and stop a process if it uses too much resources.

Typically, coding an application to "be able to restart itself" is never reliable enough. It someone were to terminate the application using `kill -9`, your application would have no ability to respond to that. Thus, the need of some type of daemon or watchdog is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would work under Linux since I've never used Mono, but what I would try is to hook into the Process.Exited event. (I'm assuming you're starting your application with the Process class)

Process.Exited
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx

So you could do something like...

-start process
-hook into exited event

-wait till exited event is called

-start process
-hook into exited event

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend this get moved to superuser.

There is nothing inherently in Mono you want to use. You could create a Watchdog application in Mono that will check and ensure your process is always running but there are plenty of Linux scripts and applications to already do this. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) is an example.

Or you can go into `/etc/inittab` and find the rows called respawn and add your daemon there. `init` will ensure that process is always running.

Here is an example daemon startup script for Java which you can modify for mono. http://shrubbery.homeip.net/c/display/W/Java+Daemon+Startup+Script